# How to use "LIMIT" in MS ACCESS using TOP without an "ORDER BY"

Tags: ms-access, select, ms-access-2007, limit

I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I want to keep the records in the exact order they are but split the data up into 9 records such as what this code would do. How do I accomplish this in MS ACCESS 2007?

I apologize, i'm fairly new to MS ACCESS and SQL queries despite the fact i'm an ABAP programmer at heart.

> SELECT * INTO CertTable1 FROM Cert LIMIT 0, 49999;
>
> SELECT * INTO CertTable2 FROM Cert LIMIT 50000, 49999;
>
> SELECT * INTO CertTable3 FROM Cert LIMIT 100000, 49999;
>
> SELECT * INTO CertTable4 FROM Cert LIMIT 150000, 49999;
>
> SELECT * INTO CertTable5 FROM Cert LIMIT 200000, 49999;
>
> SELECT * INTO CertTable6 FROM Cert LIMIT 250000, 49999;
>
> SELECT * INTO CertTable7 FROM Cert LIMIT 300000, 49999;
>
> SELECT * INTO CertTable8 FROM Cert LIMIT 350000, 49999;
>
> SELECT * INTO CertTable9 FROM Cert LIMIT 400000, 49999;

Thanks for all your help.

Waughb

Comment: "keep the records in the exact order they are"  What order is that?  Without including an ORDER BY, the order in which the database engine retrieves the records is not dependable.  If the table has a primary key index, and you haven't edited any rows since the last "compact" operation, the rows will be returned in primary key order.  However, in any other situation it will be a crap shoot.  A table is a "bag o' data".  If you want the rows out in any particular order, use ORDER BY to tell the engine your desired order.  Otherwise you take whatever you get.

Comment: Listen to HansUp! There is no order.

Comment: Why do you think the order of insertion is important?

Answer (score -1):

for example

select top 99999 * into CertTable9 from Cert where id>400000

Comment: Is ID as indicated in you're answer an autonumber or what?

Comment: This answer assumes that all integer values of `id` between `0` and `449999` are present.  If some are missing (such as from deletion) then a smaller recordset than what was asked for will be returned.  Also, it assumes that the records are sorted by `id` into ascending order, whereas the question suggests that this is unlikely.  Also, it should read `TOP 49999`.  Also, it does not offer any suggestion on how to retrieve the records for the earlier ranges, or any kind of explanation.